# Is there a way to keep the screen steady in Smash Brothers?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl, super-smash-bros-melee, super-smash-bros

If you look back at the N64 version, the screen hardly ever shakes/rumbles/tremors. I believe it only shakes during bombs and some select heavy attacks.

In the Melee and Brawl versions, however, it is almost non-stop. I have always found it annoying and that it made it hard to play long sessions and hard in general to track players. This is especially true when two people are beating each other up on the other side of the screen, the camera is zoomed out, and I am trying to fight someone else. When I do a 1v1 the screen shaking basically doesn't bother me.

You can see the difference on [this smash bros video](https://youtu.be/7xUWnQu2Grs) at [9:53](https://youtu.be/7xUWnQu2Grs?t=593) and then [10:26](https://youtu.be/7xUWnQu2Grs?t=626).

Is there an option or a cheat to turn off screen shaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Melee, [the 20XX Melee training hack pack](http://smashboards.com/threads/the-20xx-melee-training-hack-pack-3-02-update-4-0-beta01.351221/) offers the option to disable screen shake.

I don't know about the other games in the franchise.

[image: 20XX GENERAL CODES > DISABLE SCREEN RUMBLE highlighted]

Comment: O wow how cool! I'll remember this for the future. I would love to play the old Melee game in 1080p with no screen shaking :)

Comment: Can you cite or embed a screenshot?

Comment: I have still never seen the option or a video demonstrating this screen shake disable :(

Comment: @user598527 screenshot added

Comment: That looks like what I want, but I can't find any videos showing it off. I'll have to figure out how to install 20xx version of SSBM I guess. This would be such a huge deal for me (apparently only me)

Comment: This works, I finally tested it out. Six and a half years after asking the question and over two years since the proper answer, I finally have Smash bros melee without that obnoxious screen shaking. It has been 19 years since the game released haha, now I can enjoy it. The widescreen support is great too, looks amazing on ultrawide.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I've never heard a complaint about the screen shaking before - most people I know (mostly non-gamer relatives) don't even notice it until it's pointed out. You might just be one of the unlucky ones who can't handle pseudo-unpredictable shaking as well as other people can.

There is no in-game option to change screen shaking in any game. There may or may not be hacks to do so, but I'm not aware of them.

Comment: I can probably get used to it, but it kills me when I see preview videos with the shaking disabled. I love the way that looks, just like the 64 version :_(

Comment: To be honest, it's more likely that in the previews the shaking just hadn't been added to the game yet. It seems like the kind of thing they'd save for last.

Answer (score 1):

The only options that deals with the screen in Brawl are the aspect ratio and deflicker. None of these options deal with screen shaking. So no, there are no options.

I don't think the screen shaking is as quite as bad as you are saying it is, perhaps you're playing on a smaller screen than I use.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, maybe now since I have a big screen it will bother me less. I am banking more on just getting used to it. I had to do the same for Motorstorm, every single time you boost (and you boost a lot), the screen shook a lot...

Comment: The less your screen moves in general the less shaking I think you'll have.

Answer (score 1):

New developments actually permit this precise change. If you download 20XXTE, a memory file hack by Dan Salvato, and store it on your memory card, you can turn off screen rumbling in the 20XX options menu.

The file and instructions can be found at 20xx.me

Comment: cool, I guess this would work with an emulator, but probably not with a wii u version if one ever came out on the virtual console :(

Comment: Has already been answered: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243516/148510

Answer (score 0):

Technically if you do Special Brawl and set the camera mode to fixed, the screen stays at an absolute position and will not scroll or zoom at all. The only thing about this is...your records won't be affected during these battles

Comment: I can still see screen shaking in this video. Is this a correct example? It doesn't look so bad in a 1v1 setting with the camera fixed, but I still wish I could just turn it off.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCPkLXlbywU